# How many TCP connections can Ruby deal with?

Tags: ruby, linux, tcp

I have a general ubuntu server, and I want to use Ruby to deal with many TCP requests, I want to know how many connections it can handle.

Answer (score 2):

A single Ruby process can handle as many connections as the machine/ubuntu will allow the ruby process. This is a process limitation that is managed by the linux kernel. Use ulimit to increase file descriptors and you can have more socket connections. You will also need memory to handle a large number of connections and you may need to tune tcp settings.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is merely a language. Do you mean a web server running Ruby code? Then that really depends on the environment it's on, it's configuration, etc.

Comment: Then the answer is "as many as the host environment the script is running on"

Comment: So do you think there is performance problem if using Ruby to deal with too many tcp connections?

Comment: Well, I could write a script which would cause performance problems when using *one* TCP connection. Using more connections certainly means you have to think harder about your performance issues, but the issues won't be down to the number of connections you're limited to